# Manga where mc goes around the world to visit all his disciples, one of which is a king that set up a magic circle to find mc every year

Tags: story-identification, manga

If I remember right the mc design has a pendulum beside his bangs, he takes a new disciple with him from the elf realm (?) to find the other disciples

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Huh, so he has a pendulum coming off of his body by his hair? Or it's part of his costume?

Answer (score 1):

This may be *[100-nin no Eiyuu wo Sodateta Saikyou Yogensha wa, Boukensha ni Natte mo Sekaijuu no Deshi kara Shitawarete Masu](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/100-nin-no-eiyuu-wo-sodateta-saikyou-yogensha-wa-boukensha-ni-natte-mo-sekaijuu-no-deshi-kara-shitawarete-masu)*.

> Raising a hundred heroes and ending the war with an evil god, Eisen saved the world. Having received a great injury from protecting the heroes, he left for the Other World to recover. In that time, the heroes made use of their abilities to contribute greatly to the development of the world. Longing to meet again with the master they admired, they reported to him of their achievements in detail. Reading their letters, Eisen makes a decision to set out and pay each of them a visit as he travels the country to sightsee.

There are some differences, most notable the protagonist's appearance. I don't see any pendulum on his body, or anything else near his bangs.

[image: Protagonist and elf disciple]

However, it does include an elf discipline, the story starting out in another world/area, and a king that is rather obsessively seeking out his master.

[image: King looking for master]

It's possible the protagonist's appearance changes later on.